# How to detect who sent the registration form to the action?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have two different forms to register users and an action, form 1 is used by Users of type A and form 2 is used by Users of type B. Therefore when they get to index they will choose the form based on their type so I do not have any option to figure out their type, the only way is to receive the request and find out which form has sent the request to the action.

I need some hints on how can I find out which form has sent the request to the action.

jsp file of UserA

```
<s:form name="form1" action="register">
   .... registration form for User A .....
</s:form>
```

jsp file of UserB

```
<s:form name="form2" action="register">
 .... Registration form for User B .......
</s:form>
```

- please note the forms are different

action

```
public String Register() {

  if (request is from form1)
  { 
        .....
  }
  if (request is from form2)
  {
     ....
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Some options:

1. Put a hidden value in the form.
2. Look at the session user to determine their type.
3. Separate logic appropriately and have separate action methods.

Comment: @DanielMorgan Same answer. If the forms are different, using the same action/method seems silly.

Comment: so you mean I should have separate action and override all the methods for each user type?

Comment: @DanielMorgan I don't understand what that means; if you have separate actions there's no "overriding" unless you are trying to share functionality by putting shared logic in a base class.

Comment: these forms are to be used for registration, I have two different registration forms that are used to register each type of user. By over ridding I mean some functions are similar what should I do with them, for the exmaple the function that is used to save the address to database and is same for both types of users.

Comment: @DanielMorgan I still don't see any overriding, I see either (a) a base class with the shared functionality, or (b) the shared functionality lives in a service called by both actions. Without knowing more it's impossible to know what would be the "best" idea(s).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25184/discussion-between-daniel-morgan-and-dave-newton)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they already have Sessions, you can use

```
ActionContext.getContext().getSession().getId()
```

in the Struts2-Bean to identify the Session.

From now, you can differ the user1's actions and user2's actions using the Session-ID;